# Solve this Complex Equality $z^2+|z|^2 = \sqrt{2} z |z| $

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to solve this complex equation.
$z^2+|z|^2 = \sqrt{2} z |z| $

Trying to expand it by rewriting it in the (a+ib) form gets me stuck. Also, polar form does not seem helpful.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $z=0$ is one solution, for the other divide the equation by $|z|^2$ and denote $w=\tfrac{z}{|z|}$. The new equation is easier.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : Write $z=re^{i\theta}$. $e^{i\theta}$ is then the root of a certain second order polynomial. Any radius $r$ will do the job.